# Moving live site to local - issue recognising database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, https

I am attempting to download a live Wordpress site (currently in maintenance mode) to a local server to test that updates, particularly with Woocommerce, don't crash the site. All seems to be ok - I do a new Wordpress install on my localhost, add a new db in phpmyadmin, but then when I export the database and upload it, there is a problem. The content doesn't seem to be recognised. It seems to me to have something to do with the table prefixes. On the live site, they are all prefixed with wpxa (eg wpxa_posts). Importing this to a new database results in both wp prefixed tables from the fresh Wordpress install, and wpxa prefixes. I don't know why this is or if this is the problem - the live site is also running an ssl certificate, but doing a search and replace in the db file downloaded I removed all https://livesiteexample to http://localserverexample.
Would anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: What error are you getting? i mean any screenshot of current situation?

Comment: No error at the moment, but none of the pages have transferred across (as an example), nor Woocommerce settings, have transferred across. So somehow it isn't reading from the database correctly. I'm sure it's probably something really simple, but I can't see it.

Comment: Did you change the config file of database?

Comment: Ha - I have just worked it out by focusing on the prefix as the issue - I just changed wp-config to have table prefix as wpxa_ instead of wp_ and it now works.

Comment: Thanks Maha - I knew it was most likely very simple...

Answer (score 1):

The solution was very simple - I just changed wp-config to have table prefix as wpxa_ instead of wp_ and it now works.

Comment: You are right @karen. and @ Maha Dev is also right ;)